# How to: webpage equivalent of Excel pivot table

Tags: html, web-services, vba, excel

What should be the most straight-forward way (technology/framework/programing language) to get a **webpage equivalent of an Excel Pivot table**?

I have a table with raw data and I would like to be able to represent them as a pivot table depending on user choices/filters.

If possible it should be able to make some basic calculations (count, average, %) but if it would make things much more complicated, I can provide it already in the raw data (I don't know what is faster as webpage - calculating with smaller data or "just searching" with broader data).

Which technology shoud be the most appropriate for this kind of service (without being an overkill)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could acheive this in more than 1 language (and you didn't mention using third party tools) so it's hard to recommend one over the other... Since you mentioning VBa I suspect VB.NET would be a good starting point.

Although you can embed Excel into webpages. Check out the Excel Web App

More details are here http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/web-apps-help/introduction-to-excel-web-app-HA010378338.aspx

> When you open your workbook in SkyDrive or SharePoint, Excel Web App
>   opens the workbook in the browser, where you can move around the
>   workbook, sort, filter, expand and collapse PivotTables, and even
>   recalculate the workbook.

Here is a general demo of it working: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/embed-an-excel-spreadsheet-on-a-web-page-FX102602477.aspx

Comment: Excellent! I didn't know that. Just one more question as I can't find it in their documentation (and as I don't have yet any experience with SharePoint and Excel Web App): **Would it work with excels containing VBA (e.g. UDFs)?**

Comment: You need to play and find out, I'm sorry, I don't know.

Comment: The pivotTable field list isn't available within embeded workbooks though. Which is a shame. It works fine when you're not embedding.